# Simplifying a proof of Langlands-Tunnnell Theorem

Tags: algebraic-geometry, arithmetic-geometry

I read *[A SIMPLIFIED PROOF OF SERRE’S CONJECTURE](https://arxiv.org/abs/2108.07577)* recent paper by Luis Victor Dieulefait, Ariel Martín Pacetti to understand the proof of Serre's modularity theorem. According to this paper, the proof of Serre's modularity theorem is used Langlands-Tunnnell Theorem. The proof of Langlands-Tunnnell Theorem need lie group, L group, trace formula and so on. I think that these ingredients and -dral cases used in this proof is slightly redundant. It's been decades since the Langlands-Tunnell Theorem was proven, but is there a simple proof of this?

Comment: Why do you think that Dickson’s classification of solvable subgroups of $PGL_2(\Bbb F_p)$ is "slightly redundant"?

Comment: The statement of Langlands-Tunnell theorem don't need Dickson’s classification. If one can prove all cases at once, I think that would be more concise.

Comment: The proof of Serre's result uses that we may assume that the image of $\rho$ is non-solvable. So we have to deal with the solvable case before - so with Dickson. Of course, perhaps this can be avoided, but I don't see a problem using it.

Comment: Yes. In this paper, authors prove the case that $\rho$ is solvable by Langlands-Tunnnell theorem whence prove the case that $\rho$ is non-solvable. If Serre's modularity theorem were proved without it, it would much simpler. However it's recent that Khare-Wintenberger-Kisin proved Serre's modularity theorem. Hence I can't expect it. In fact this paper itself try to simplify the proof.

Comment: On the other hand Langlands-Tunnell theorem was proved some decades ago. Thus, the proof may be simplistic. I understand that if one can prove it, it is good enough but I think that making the proofs simpler will make it easier for more people to learn.